# textarea in table

Tags: php, textarea

Please tell me how I can hide textarea in td table, what attribute must I use?

```
<td class='odd text'><textarea placeholder='Start time' ></textarea>  </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as hiding anything else: `style="display:none"`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems having the table in this question makes no difference. To make the textarea hidden set the style attribute `display:none` like so:

```
<td class='odd text'><textarea placeholder='Start time' style="display:none" ></textarea>  </td>
```